# How to add line numbers in text of inserted documents?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

I write a Word 2013 document, where I often use the **insert object** function. There are also Word 2013 documents to insert, containing source code. For those documents I want to show line numbers in the inserting document. Enabling line numbering in both documents does not work.

Does anybody know how to show line numbering for inserted Word 2013 objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found myself a way to show line numbers in **INSERTED** documents:

1. Open the **document to insert**
2. Create a **new style** (or modify e.g. style "Normal")
3. Open **Format / Numbering** and enable a numbering format of your choice
4. Save your document
5. Insert your document and you'll see line numbers for the inserted text

Comment: Just checked: Works also for Word 2013

Answer (score 0):

Can you process the files outside of word ?

If you have awk you can run the source code
through an awk script which will number it for you.
If you are on unix or have a unix like shell:

```
$ cat source_file | awk '{N++; print N," ",$0}' > numbered_file
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to PAGE LAYOUT in office 2013 tabs then Line Numbers and then in drop down menu click Line Numbering options.. then in new pop-up window go to layout tab then Line Numbers.., Tick Add line numbering, click OK then you are done

[Detailed](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/add-line-numbers-word-2013-documents/)

Comment: Read carefully... You describe a way I've already tried out.